# Removes duplicates from listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to display items on a listbox, those items are duplicated in my worksheet, but when I want to show the listbox i want to show unique items, I tried to work with collections but it didnt help me.
My code to populate my listbox is :

```
            Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne).Activate

            fin_col_Form_Init = ws.Cells(6, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
            UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnCount = 4
            UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnWidths = "300;100;100;100"

            For i = 2 To fin_col_Form_Init
                UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.AddItem ws.Cells(6, i)
                UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(7, i)
                UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(8, i)
                UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ListCount - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(9, i)
            Next i
        end if 
    Sample
end sub
```

Where Sub is:

```
Sub Sample()
    RemovelstDuplicates ctrlListNames
End Sub
```

Where RemovelstDuplicates is:

```
 Public Sub RemovelstDuplicates(lst As msforms.ListBox)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With lst
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            For j = .ListCount - 1 To (i + 1) Step -1
                If .List(j) = .List(i) Then
                    .RemoveItem j
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I got an error on the Sample code

Comment: What error and where?

Comment: You try to remove the duplicates from the listbox named `ctrlListNames` but you addad the items to a listbox named `ListBox_Form_Init`. So probaly `RemovelstDuplicates UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init`?

Comment: @SJR teh error says: ByRef argument type mismatch 

The error is on ctrlListNames

Comment: As you have a function that deletes content it searches, the reliability of the function can be increased by setting the i-loop with step -1 to avoid skipping entries.

Comment: It works thank you, I edited the name of the listbox and it works thank you everyone @FabeDuru and SJR and Pᴇʜ

Answer (score 2):

I edited the code (changed the name of my listbox):

```
Sub Sample()
    RemovelstDuplicates ctrlListNames
End Sub
```

To

```
Sub Sample()
    RemovelstDuplicates UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init
End Sub
```

And its working
Thanks to all